# Dao class don't perform insert or update on spring-boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-orm

In my current spring-boot application, I have this hibernate configuration:

```
# jdbc.X
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mystore?charSet=LATIN1
spring.datasource.username=klebermo
spring.datasource.password=123

# hibernate.X
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

which create the database tables and insert the data from `data.sql` without problems, but when I try insert or update an entity through a view, no data is inserted, despite no error is triggered.

the submission from the form is handled by this methods from my controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.cadastra(object);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "altera", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void altera(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.altera(object);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void remove(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.remove(object);
  }
```

in my service class I have:

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void cadastra(E object) {
    dao.insert(object);
  }

  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'altera_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void altera(E object) {
    dao.update(object);
  }

  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'remove_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void remove(E object) {
    dao.delete(object);
  }
```

and in my dao class:

```
@Transactional
public void insert(E object) {
    getEntityManager().persist(object);
}

@Transactional
public void update(E object) {
    getEntityManager().merge(object);
}

@Transactional
public void delete(E object) {
    getEntityManager().remove(object);
}
```

anyone can see what's wrong here?

Comment: "cadastra" is your insert right? Are you sure cadastra method are called?

Comment: @user23123412 yes. it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this pŕoblem using this structure to the methods of my dao class:

```
public void insert(E object) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(object);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: Do you have `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotated in the Java Config classes? `@Transactional` should abstract the "begin" "commit" for you.